# Javascript function not being executed. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to print a table in html without refreshing the page, all this based on the selection from a drop down menu. I'm accessing my database and populating the drop down menu correctly, but when it is time for the table to appear, the script is not even being executed.

I'm sure there is something more I should be doing but I don't know what.

**main.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showCustomer(str){
    var choice = str.value;

    var xmlhttp;
    if (choice==0){         
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML="No person selected";
        return;
    }
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function();{
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;          
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","showtable.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>


<p>
<form>
<select name="customer" onchange="showCustomer(this)">
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=lab9",$username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"));
    $dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM customers");
//echo "<p>";
//echo "<select name=\"customer\" onchange=\"".<script>showCustomer(this.value)</script>;."\">";
$zero=0;
echo "<option value=".$zero.">Select person</option>";
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($result as $row)
{
      //unset($id, $name);
      $id = $row['id'];
      $name = $row['name']; 
      echo "<option value=".$id.">".$name."</option>";                 
}
?> 
</select>
</form>
</p>


<p id="display"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**showtable.php**

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=lab9",$username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"));
    $dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("SELECT id,name,adress,city,tk,phone,mobile FROM customers WHERE id=".$q."");
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row){
    echo "<p>";
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>ID</td><td>".$row['id']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Name</td><td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Adress</td><td>".$row['adress']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Town</td><td>".$row['city']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Τ.Κ.</td><td>".$row['tk']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Telephone number</td>".$row['phone']."<td></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Mobile</td><td>".$row['mobile']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</p>";
}


?>
```

Comment: *"the script is not even being executed."* which script? how are you confirming this?

Comment: @KevinB I'm sorry I meant the showCustomer function.

Comment: It should be getting called

Comment: @KevinB I am being really bad in my description. I mean that the only thing shown in the browser is the dropdown menu, and when I'm selecting different options, nothing from the function is being executed.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. I think the function IS being executed, it just isn't updating the display div the way you expect.

Comment: Change `function();{` to `function(){`. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Xufox said, change `function();{` to `function() {`. Also at the **showtable.php**, your `"SELECT id,name,adress,city,tk,phone,mobile FROM customers WHERE id=".$q.""` maybe you made a typo ? From adress to address? Let me know if that helps!